# How do I install CUDA?

Tags: software-installation, cuda

How do I install cuda on 14.04? nvidia-cuda-toolkit got removed from this distribution.

I tried installing cuda 6.0 toolkit from nvidia's website, but it only says it works for 13.10, so that didn't work either (not surprisingly).

Comment: Currently trying with a fresh install instead of the upgrade from 13.10 in case that makes a difference.

Comment: had any lack with this? I am on a 14.04 64bit system too. I did find `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` and installed it. I have `nvcc` and the `libcuda.so` but I can't find the samples configuration to build and verify an example.

Comment: Have a look at this : [Installing and testing CUDA in Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451672/installing-and-testing-cuda-in-ubuntu-14-04)