# Installing and testing CUDA in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, nvidia, software-installation, cuda

I am uncertain about how to install CUDA in my system. 
looking around there are many tutorials about cuda on 12.04 LTS and a few on 13.04 and 13.10, but they all talk about acquiring a `deb` package from the [NVidia CUDA developer zone](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).

Well NVidia does not offer a Debian package for 14.04 as of yet.

However, there is a promising package in `apt` repository: `nvidia-cuda-toolkit`.

The problem is that I didn't find any example with it. At least not the examples that are referred to in [cuda6 online documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html) section 4.11.

I should mention that the toolkit installed is v5.5, not v6 but I haven't found documentation for cuda v5.5 on the NVidia website.

So I can verify that `nvcc` is there, but nothing further than that. How can I get some examples to run to verify the CUDA is installed properly?

Comment: @Chris.Wilson I was following your instruction and everything was fine; but at the ./deviceQuery stage my machine said no CUDA-capable device is detected. My machine has Nvidia GTX780. Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: My Ubuntu 14.04 complains: "E: Unable to locate package nvidia-cuda-toolkit". Maybe because I have a 64-bit server distribution? Do you know how I can install CUDA on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit server?

Comment: Probably need to add the nvidia repo to your sources

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov [nvidia-cuda-toolkit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nvidia-cuda-toolkit) is part of multiverse, which you may need to [enable](http://askubuntu.com/q/89096/165556).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I got Cuda6 working on Lubuntu 14.04. This already had build-essentials installed, so if you're using a fresh install, you should probably install it:

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

[Download](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_0/rel/installers/cuda_6.0.37_linux_64.run) the cuda6 run package (6.0.37 at the current time of writing) to `~/Downloads`:

Open up a terminal and extract the separate installers via:

```
mkdir ~/Downloads/nvidia_installers;
cd ~/Downloads
./cuda_6.0.37_linux_64.run -extract=~/Downloads/nvidia_installers;
```

(I tried running the .run file directly, but it kept screwing up my Xorg install and would never let X run. I believe it is a config issue between driver versions: those installed by `apt-get nvidia-331-updates` and the cuda*.run driver.)

Completely uninstall anything in the Ubuntu repositories with nvidia-*. I used synaptic and did a purge, AKA completely uninstall programs and configuration.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove "nvidia-*"
```

Have these instructions handy as we need to kill X install the driver.
Press  <kbd>CTL</kbd>  + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to drop to the physical terminal and log in.

```
cd ~/Downloads/nvidia_installers;
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo killall Xorg
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.62.run
```

Accept the EULA and install the driver. I would recommend letting it update Xorg config files.

After that installer finishes, turn on the nvidia module and install CUDA.

```
sudo modprobe nvidia
sudo ./cuda-linux64-rel-6.0.37-18176142.run
sudo ./cuda-samples-linux-6.0.37-18176142.run
```

test if the drivers are working by going to your sample directory

```
cd /usr/local/cuda/samples
sudo chown -R <username>:<usergroup> .
cd 1_Utilities/deviceQuery
make .
./deviceQuery
```

Worked for me at this point.
Now restart X

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

You should be able to do

```
lsmod | grep nv
```

and see a line with nvidia listed. 
Don't forget to log back out of your physical terminal if it all worked.

**APPENDIX**

In my case it was necessary to add the folder that contains the executable to your `$PATH`.

One way of doing it is to edit the `~/.bashrc` file in your Home folder.
Add a line to your .`bashrc` (modify the location if you changed the default CUDA installation folder)

> export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.0/bin:$PATH

Save the file and then source your `.bashrc` by typing

```
source .bashrc
```

when in your home folder.

Comment: @tohnperfect: you might need to 
    modprobe nvidia 
after the driver install so that the ./deviceQuery actually hits the nvidia driver. Did it happen to work after a reboot? If so, the nvidia driver probably wasn't actually loaded.

Comment: Notes: 1) On my system the package is called `build-essential`, not `build-essentials` 2) I don't have X to stop, as I run a server variant without X 3) sudo modprobe nvidia goes `FATAL` at this point, looks like the driver wasn't installed? My version of the recipe is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7470107/), but it doesn't work.

Comment: When I install driver with `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.62.run`, I get an [this error](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7470133/). In `/var/log/nvidia-installer.log` I see the [following lines](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7470144/). When I try `make oldconfig && make prepare` I get [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7470147/). At this point I gave up.

Comment: The correct build essential package name is "build-essential" (no s).

Comment: It is not necessary to extract the .run file. Instead, just supply the appropriate command line options. E.g., `sudo ./cuda_6.0.37_linux_64.run -driver -silent` to install the driver, `sudo ./cuda_6.0.37_linux_64.run -toolkit -samples -silent -override` to install the toolkit and samples (use `-help` for more options). Also, better not `chmod` the samples directly: the toolkit contains a script `cuda-install-samples-6.0.sh` in its bin directory to copy them to a local location.

Comment: I'm getting a Fatal error: can't create `deviceQuery.o: Permission Denied` . What am I to do? Sorry I'm new to linux. I did `chmod -R root *` before. @Chris.Wilson Besides, I do not know if it is due to the driver, but I can log in but nothing happens after that. The screen remains frozen.

Comment: Does this still work if I want to install CUDA purely for parallel processing purposes, and I don't want my graphics card to be used for rendering?

Comment: I get a pre-install script error and finally it fails to install.

Answer (score 30):

For CUDA-6.5 I followed [this](http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/cuda-installation/cuda6.5-ubuntu) simple tutorial:

Download the .deb  [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)  then

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin:$PATH   #CUDA' >> ~/.bashrc
```

That's everything I needed to start coding on a fresh 14.04.1 install with my GTX 750ti. It installs the nvidia-340 driver. deviceQuery and all of the other samples ran properly after I compiled them.

Comment: This worked well for me (got CUDA 7.0).  It took a long time to download the files (during the apt-get install) but it now works.

Comment: CUDA 7.5 is at http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/cuda-installation/cuda7.5-ubuntu

Answer (score 20):

I have installed the `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` package this morning on a fresh 14.04. I also installed the nvidia driver (version `331.38` marked as tested) from the additional driver interface.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Up to now everything seems to work well (`nvcc` is here, display is correct). You need to restart to use the new driver.

As you mentioned this is CUDA 5.5 but in my case it's not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Quick and easy solution that worked for me (cuda 5.5, Lubuntu 14.04 64-bit):

> Make sure you're using nvidia's propietary driver (331.38 for me) from Start menu-> Preferences->Software & Updates.

Download the .deb package for your Ubuntu release from Nvidia's [site](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).

Add repo:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1304_6.0-37_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
```

Get dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev
```

Get the toolkit:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

**(Optional)** Get nsight IDE:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-nsight
```

And you're ready to go!

Answer (score 1):

I installed cuda 6 using the package(cuda_6.0.37_linux_64.run) from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) . Unfortunately, I failed to install the driver. Although Toolkit(CUDA 6) was installed, it didn't pass the sample test:

> ./deviceQuery Starting...
>
> CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)
>
> cudaGetDeviceCount returned 3
> -> initialization error
> Result = FAIL

I've also tested nvidia-334, nvidia-371 from ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa. The results is worse. Both CUDA 5 and CUDA 6 failed to pass the sample test.

In summary, CUDA 6 is not working on Ubuntu 14.04. But CUDA 5.5+nvidia-331 is OK. And you can verify cuda by testing cuda-5.5 samples.

Comment: `cuda-5.5 samples` are in /usr/share/doc/?

Comment: It depends. Please check /usr/local/cuda/samples/. It it doesn't exist, you can download .run from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads and only install samples. It'll be installed to ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-5.5_Samples/ by default.

Answer (score 1):

I got the  [cuda 6 release](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_0/rel/installers/cuda_6.0.37_linux_64.run) installed and the samples to work on ubuntu 14.04. First I installed the nvidia driver 334.21 (NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-334.21.run), then just used the cuda_6.0.37_linux_64.run script.

First I downloaded NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-334.21.run from [nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx), then logged out of the ubuntu desktop to the login screen. Then logged in remotely over ssh from my laptop and shutdown lightdm `sudo service lightdm stop` to stop X running, then ran the install script `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-334.21.run`, then restarted lightdm `sudo service lightdm start`. Then rebooted. Verified that hardware acceleration was working by running the UrbanTerror game (not suitable for young children!! but now running at 90+ fps instead of 20fps). I also installed libXi and libXmu packages through synaptic.

Then to installed cuda 6: I downloaded cuda_6.0.37_linux_64.run from nvidia, and installed it using `sudo cuda_6.0.37_linux_64.run --override` otherwise it complained about not supporting the environment. I think I had to tell it not to overwrite the 334 driver during the install, otherwise accepted defaults. To compile examples I did `cd ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-6.0_Samples` and `make`. The examples appeared under bin, a few needed to be run as eg `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64 ./MersenneTwisterGP11213` otherwise they couldn't find the libcurand.so.6.0 library, but no other problems I noticed.

I don't know if installing using `--override` is risky, but so far so good for my install.

my system:
ubuntu 14.04, AMD FX-8350 CPU, nvidia GTX750 GPU (Maxwell architecture)

I've got the build-essentials package installed, but not nvidia-cuda-toolkit

Answer (score 1):

I got CUDA 6.0 up and working on 14.04 using the following steps.

Install the nvidia-331, nvidia-331-dev and nvidia-331-uvm packages from [xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) using instructions for adding the ppa from [here](http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/).

Install CUDA 6.0 using the "-extract" method above, except *ignore the steps for installing the driver and instead rely on the packages*. Only install the compiler and samples.

Answer (score -1):

I installed and tested it using this.

https://gist.github.com/mGalarnyk/f3b78fb90ca58855bba01738dd88ef2c#file-install_cuda_7-5_ubuntu_14_04

```
# http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64/
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.5-18_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.5-18_amd64.deb
rm cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.5-18_amd64.deb
echo 'export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export CUDA_ROOT=/usr/local/cuda
export PATH=$PATH:$CUDA_ROOT/bin:$HOME/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CUDA_ROOT/lib64
' >> ~/.bashrc

# Let terminal know of the changes to the .bashrc file
source .bashrc

sudo apt-get update 

# y flag just says yes to all prompts
sudo apt-get install -y cuda

# Check if installation is successful by running the next line
# nvcc -V
```