# cuda6.0 does not run on 14.04

Tags: cuda

I have installed on my homegrown system a GeFporce 450GTS graphics card an should like to use its GPU in my hobby projects(mainly chess in either C++ or Python)The current cuda6.0 package installs without a hitch, including the shipped research driver, howevet the examples don't run:there is no device.
How can I detect if this is a Ubuntu or a NVIDIA problem. I am not trying to put the blame on a specific doorstep, but i want to solve an honest to Allah technical problem and I am trying to do that for some years now
An angry old man
joop renes

Answer (score 0):

I have had an headache trying to install Cuda 6.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. After looking out for solutions I have come to the conclusion that cuda6 does not run on Ubuntu 14.04. The version available for Ubuntu 14.04 is lagging behind NVIDIA CUDA toolkit 6.

You could try:
[Installing and testing CUDA in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451672/installing-and-testing-cuda-in-ubuntu-14-04/462525#462525)

I installed Cuda 5.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 and it works fine. I have the nvidia 331 driver installed.

I reckon you installed Cuda 5.5 on Ubuntu 14.04. It seems to work better than Cuda6.