# CUDA 7.0 test failed on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I followed nvidia official guide to install cuda-7.0, but I had a few problems they didn't provide a complete explanation. And my test samples cannot be built by `make`. I'll explain the several mistakes I found during the installation.

#### environment

I'm working on a 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04, with `NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GT 640 OEM]` returned by `lspci | grep -i nvidia`. My gcc version is 4.4.7.

#### package

I downloaded from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads the "Linux x86 -> Ubuntu 14.04 -> Local Package Installer", which it doesn't provide a md5 value to check. But later the installation was fine as it seems.

#### installation

I did:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda*.deb # returned: OK
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

#### test

As official guide said, I have to setup environment path first. I changed to:

```
cd /usr/local/cuda-7.0
```

and I can add path:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Here's the first problem: the path is lost whenever I close the terminal. Since I can check it with `nvcc -V` where we have nvcc under the first directory.

When I tried to compile the samples:

```
cd /usr/local/cuda-7.0/samples
sudo make
```

Finally it returned errors:

```
make[1]: entering directory `/usr/local/cuda-7.0/samples/2_Graphics/Mandelbrot'
/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++   -m64      -gencode
arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode
arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode
arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode
arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 -o Mandelbrot Mandelbrot.o Mandelbrot_cuda.o Mandelbrot_gold.o  -L../../common/lib/linux/x86_64 -L/usr/lib/"nvidia-346" -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXi -lXmu -lglut -lGLEW
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libnvidia-tls.so.346.46, needed by /usr/lib/nvidia-346/libGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libnvidia-glcore.so.346.46, needed by /usr/lib/nvidia-346/libGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/nvidia-346/libGL.so：‘_nv018tls’ undefined reference
...
# list of undefined reference
```

And I cannot go further.

#### other checks

- `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version` doesn't work since `/proc/driver` doesn't have the directory `nvidia/`.
- `/dev/nvidia*` doesn't exits.
- `nvidia-smi` command not found.

These problems exist after reboot.

---

#### some fixes

Fixed path and lib settings by adding those two lines under `~/.profile` for current user:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And found a useful link: [Installing and testing CUDA in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451672/installing-and-testing-cuda-in-ubuntu-14-04) it seems I need to install by run file instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several trials I finally found the solution. Installation of CUDA is a pain, for which keeps corrupting my system configuration that I have no way to revert.

The solution for the installation **must be done in tty1** (the command line) mode, because it needs to kill GUI service before installing NVIDIA drivers, or it will refuse to work. And we need `.run` file. With reasons I can't know the .deb files never correctly configure themselves, and I never got them work. look [Installing and testing CUDA in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451672/installing-and-testing-cuda-in-ubuntu-14-04) for a similar solution.

Need to mention, according to my trails:

- installation via apt cannot succeed.
- installation via deb files cannot succeed.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
Running the following command helped me test and understand the problem:

`ldd /usr/lib/nvidia-346/libGL.so.346.46`

Finally, adding the following to my `~/.profile` solved the problem:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-346:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

as indeed the `/usr/lib/nvidia-346` path was not given to the linker.

Comment: Can you write a more thorough answer that how did you find the problem out and when do we execute the commands chronologically? Then I might can change the accepted answer to this one. It's an old question, that some trivial I can't remember now. But I checked quick, in my laptop (we don't have CUDA, but have nvidia-*), dynamic lib path doesn't necessarily include `/usr/lib/nvidia-*`.

Comment: The ld problem is reported during the compilation, but does your CUDA provides you `/proc/driver/nvidia/version` and `nvidia-smi`? That's the real problem, because these effects are global. You must need CUDA somewhere else. Will it work? Not only the samples?

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue, on Ubuntu 14.04, x86_64 with cuda 7.5.
The warnings were:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libnvidia-tls.so.352.63, needed by /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libnvidia-glcore.so.352.63, needed by /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

This was the output of `ldd /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so`:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc1c5d4000)
libnvidia-tls.so.352.63 =>
libnvidia-glcore.so.352.63 =>
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f161512e000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f1614f1c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1614b57000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1614952000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-(0x00007f1615488000)gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f161464c000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f161442d000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000557aa9c51000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f1614228000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f1614022000)
```

I added the following line to `~/.zshrc` (`~/.bashrc`...if you are using bash):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-352:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Thus, the following are the entries related to cuda in my `~/.zshrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-352:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then I sourced `~/.zshrc`

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Now `ldd /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so` shows:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc1c5d4000)
libnvidia-tls.so.352.63 => tls/libnvidia-tls.so.352.63 (0x00007f1617f1c000)
libnvidia-glcore.so.352.63 (0x00007f1615488000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f161512e000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f1614f1c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1614b57000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1614952000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f161464c000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f161442d000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000557aa9c51000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f1614228000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f1614022000)
```

After this the `make` inside `NVIDIA_CUDA-7.5_Samples` directory completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I installed using the .deb package from nvidia website on Ubuntu 14.04. Solution for me was:

- add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-346:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to ~/.bashrc
- open terminal type:
- cd to the samples folder
- `sudo bash`
- `source ~./bashrc`
- check if /usr/lib/nvidia-346 is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- `make -j`

This solved it for me.

I have the feeling, there are some permission issues when installing CUDA using the cuda-repo-ubuntuXXX_amd64.deb file.
I have the