# Upgrading CUDA from 6.5 to 7

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

On Ubuntu 14.04, I have CUDA 6.5 installed. I want to upgrade to CUDA 7.0. So, I followed the instructions at [Installing and testing CUDA in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451672/installing-and-testing-cuda-in-ubuntu-14-04), but using the CUDA 7 run file instead of CUDA 6.5. After doing this, I rebooted my machine, and ran `nvcc --version`. However, this prints out `Cuda compilation tools, release 6.5, V6.5.16`. Why has CUDA 7.0 not been installed properly?

Answer (score 2):

It could this known issue I found in the official CUDA 7 documentation: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#resolved-issues-title.

In section 7.1, the second point states this:

"The Canonical repackaging of the NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu 14.04 may fail to upgrade cleanly to the latest version due to conflicts with the /etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd file. To address this issue, remove the nvidia-opencl-icd-* package and then try the upgrade again. For more information, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331-updates/+bug/1328762."