# this installation did not install the CUDA driver

Tags: 14.04, cuda

I'm currently trying to install cuda on my ubuntu 14.04. I downloaded cuda run file from nvidia: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?sid=908551

But i get the following error:

[image]

EDIT:
settings->software&updates->additional drivers 
the options are all grayed out:
[image]

Comment: That screen shot is imposable to read, remove it and paste any errors as text, into your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing and testing CUDA in Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451672/installing-and-testing-cuda-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: wait, can't you click on the screen shot to zoom in

Comment: Sure, but that is not how we do things here, you need to add the code to the question and format it correctly, it is easier to read and has syntax highlighting, why should we help you if you can't be bothered to present your question in a way that helps us to help you ?

Comment: Does the image not also include the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For installing cuda 1st you need to install nvidia driver as for best scenario use propitiatory nvidia driver which are in settings >> software and updates >> Additional driver.

And select nvidia 343 or nvidia 346 driver but not the lower version as for cuda.

After when you install the propitiatory driver reboot the system and install

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-346-uvm` or

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-343-uvm` or

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-346-updates-uvm` or

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-343-updates-uvm`

According to the driver you've installed and then create an alias for that uvm in blaclist files for nouveau driver by

alias nvidia-346-uvm  or whichever you have installed

then update the initramfs by

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

then reboot and run

`sudo modeprobe nvidia-343-uvm` to load nvidia kernel module and then

retry to install your cuda

Comment: Seems you missed alot of steps according too this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/451672/installing-and-testing-cuda-in-ubuntu-14-04 Did you test this or paste it from another site ?

Comment: i'd install cuda 7 using nvidia-346-updates driver in ubuntu 15.04 `3.19.0-25-generic` just the additional steps may be the /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file in which alias to be edited.And the work is done.

Comment: And as the link you have mentioned it seems to me that that guy build the nvidia kernel module from run file which takes lots of time and sometime result in failure as this is shortcut and provide best solution in minimum time.

Comment: Thats fine, I was more thinking, you could of just pasted it from a website with no knowledge of the subject, or consequences, your response was solid so +1

Comment: actually it's my personal experience fro setting dual monitor setup using bumblebee, nvidia and cuda.

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean, you seem to know what you are talking about, so no worries

Comment: I went to settings >> software and updates >> Additional driver but everything is grayed out. I uploaded the image on my post.

In addition, I already installed a nvidia driver for my computer with instructions posted on this stackoverflow link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver (the second answer)

So the only thing i want to install is cuda. is that possible?

Comment: first remove the manually installed nvidia driver by <p> `sudo apt-get remove nvidia*&&sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`<p>and also delete the blacklist configuration you have created <p> then reboot now follow the procedure, install the nvidia-346-updates driver only and if stuck somewhere comment i help you out.

Comment: alias nvidia-346-uvm : 

this keeps telling me that nvidia-346-uvm is not found

Comment: which nvidia driver you have installed

Comment: i installed nvidia-346-uvm. settings >> software and updates >> Additional driver, they are not grayed out anymore

Comment: no means driver from additional driver in settings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26582/discussion-between-jayc-and-gaurav).

Comment: umm so i rebooted ubuntu, and now im getting an error when i run deviceQuery : cudaGetDeviceCount returned 30

Comment: nvm you need to run with sudo

Comment: just run `sudo modprobe nvidia-346-uvm` and then do whatever you wanna and also to run program in nsight eclipse you need to run `sudo nsight-eclipse`