# nvcc: Command not find after installed nvidia-cuda-dev on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, cuda

I installed `nvidia-cuda-dev` on ubuntu 16.04 using `sudo apt-get install`. But when I try to install caffe, it says `make: /usr/lib/bin/nvcc: Command not found`. I guess maybe the `nvcc` location is wrong. But I can't find nvcc using `sudo find / -name "nvcc"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing and testing CUDA in Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451672/installing-and-testing-cuda-in-ubuntu-14-04), particularly [this answer](/a/455758/175814).

Answer (score 3):

`nvcc` is in the package `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` (see [this package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=nvcc)).

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!