# As of 2017, can I have a fully functional GPU in an Ubuntu computer?

Tags: drivers, cuda, gpu

A few years ago I read that there were no drivers for GPU cards. I am sure the thing has changed for good. I am a scientist working with Fortran 200X and some C++ and I would like to learn how to code in parallel (CUDA is called the platform, though I am not sure it is the only one) in an Ubuntu laptop.

Are there GPU cards fully supported in Ubuntu? I mean, fully supported in a stable way, not some experimental stuff.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shopping recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Some of us have been using graphics cards with Linux since more than five years.  Also see: https://askubuntu.com/q/61396/158442, https://askubuntu.com/q/451672/158442, https://askubuntu.com/q/799184/158442 (I'm using a 1080Ti now, and playing games on Linux)